# React - Can we use axios interceptors at app.js instead of index.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Can we use axios interceptors at app.js instead of index.js? I just want to know if there is any drawback of using it inside app.js or inside any other file instead of index.js. For my scenario, I have to check if user is authorized for every back-end request call, and have to update local state on the basis of interceptor's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a interceptor file and include it any when you want to use axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

 const axiosInterceptor =  axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

  if (response.status === 401) {
    console.log("You are not authorized");
    //redirect
  }
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  if (error.response && error.response.data) {
    return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
  }
  return Promise.reject(error.message);
});

export default axiosInterceptor;
```

And in your component

```
import axiosInterceptor from './utils/axiosInterceptor.js'
```

Comment: I think we use it once at index.js. My question is 'can I use it at any file? Or it matters to use it on different files?